What does a typerror impl means?
I am navigating to a new page and I get the following error:
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building Expanded(flex: 1):
Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Expanded
The code is as follows:
Ontap function is called first

   onTap: () { 
                          return TimerScreen.pushRoute(
                          context,
                          timer.selfRef!,
                          readOnly,
                          timerSessionUrl,
                          timerEditCubit: context.read<TimerEditCubit>(),
                        );},


class TimerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TimerScreen({
    required this.timerSessionUrl,
    required this.readOnly,
    required this.timerRef,
    super.key,
  });
  final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> timerRef;
  final bool readOnly;
  final String timerSessionUrl;

  static void pushRoute(
    BuildContext context,
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> timerRef,
    bool readOnly,
    String timerSessionUrl, {
    TimerEditCubit? timerEditCubit,
    Function(BuildContext, Route) push = Navigator.push,
  }) {
    push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider.value(
              value: context.read<ExecutionCubit>(),
            ),
         
          ],
          child: TimerScreen(
            timerRef: timerRef,
            readOnly: readOnly,
            timerSessionUrl: timerSessionUrl,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // detect mobile screen
    final bool isMobile = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600;

    return BlocListener<MessagesCubit, CollectionState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        final lastMessage =
            context.read<MessagesCubit>().getNewMessageAndNotify();
        if (lastMessage == null) return;
        showAlertBanner(
          context,
          () {},
          AlertBannerWidget(text: lastMessage),
        );
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<TimerEditCubit, DocumentState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is DocumentSuccess<TimerModel>) {
          ....
              },
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is DocumentSuccess<ExecutionModel>) {
                  final exec = state.model;

                  return PopScope(
                    canPop: !readOnly,
                    child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        backgroundColor:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                        title: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(timer.title),
                            if (!readOnly)
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (_) => TimerEditScreen(
                                        timerRef: timer.selfRef!,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        actions: const <Widget>[FullscreenButton()],
                      ),
                   
                      body: TwoColumnLayout(
                        leftBuilder: (_, constraints, twoColumns) {
                          return [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  showQRDialog(context, timerSessionUrl),
                              child: const Text('Show QR Code'),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: twoColumns
                                  ? constraints.maxHeight - 32
                                  : null,
                              width: constraints.maxWidth,
                              child: TimerCountdownWidget(
                                key: ValueKey(timer.hashCode),
                                deactivateButtons:
                                    exec.activeTimerRef != null &&
                                        exec.activeTimerRef != timer.selfRef,
                                execution: exec.activeTimerRef == timer.selfRef
                                    ? exec
                                    : null,
                                timer: timer,
                               .....
                            ),
                          ];
                        },
                        rightBuilder: (_, __, twoColumns) {
                          final field = rightBuilderWidget(timer, twoColumns);
                          return [
                            twoColumns
                                ? Expanded(
                                    child: field,
                                  )
                                : field,
                          ];
                        },
                      ),
                     .....
    );
  }

  Widget rightBuilderWidget(TimerModel timer, bool twoColumns) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        if (timer.imageFile != null && timer.imageFile!.isNotEmpty) ...{
          twoColumns
              ? Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: FacilifyCachedNetworkImage(
                      isFullScreenEnable: true,
                      imageUrl: timer.imageFile ?? ''),
                )
              : FacilifyCachedNetworkImage(
                  isFullScreenEnable: true, imageUrl: timer.imageFile ?? ''),
        },
        if (timer.fleatherDescription.isNotEmpty) ...{
          twoColumns
              ? Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: getFleatherFieldWidget(twoColumns, timer),
                )
              : getFleatherFieldWidget(twoColumns, timer),
        }
      ],
    );
  }

class TwoColumnLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const TwoColumnLayout({
    required this.leftBuilder,
    required this.rightBuilder,
    super.key,
    this.minWidthForRow = 800,
  });

  final ColumnBuilder leftBuilder;
  final ColumnBuilder rightBuilder;

  final double minWidthForRow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final twoColumns = constraints.maxWidth > constraints.maxHeight &&
          constraints.maxWidth >= minWidthForRow;
      if (twoColumns) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded( //These line here
              child: Column(
                children: leftBuilder(
                  context,
                  constraints.copyWith(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth / 2),
                  twoColumns,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded( //Also this line here
              child: Column(
                children: rightBuilder(
                  context,
                  constraints.copyWith(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth / 2),
                  twoColumns,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],

    );

The error is pointing to the expanded in the two column layout widget.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Expanded

It seems like there's a problem with a widget called Expanded in your code. The error says it's getting a null value unexpectedly...
The error is happening in the Two Column Layout widget where Expanded is used. It seems like there's an unexpected null value being encountered. Doublecheck the values being passed to the Expanded widgets, particularly inside the right Builder function. Make sure that all the required data is properly initialized before being used.
